# Opencart 3.0.3.8. How can I add subcategory images to default Opencart 'Category' module

Tags: module, opencart-3

I am looking to repurpose the 'Category' module into a full page subcategory wall on top level categories that have no products. All the info I need is currently in the default Opencart 'Category' module except the subcategory images. So my question is, how can I add the category images into the 'Category' module as per my image here :

[Category module in left hand column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hvPA.png).

Any pointers would be gratefully received.
TIA

I have tried a couple of older solutions for earlier versions, but I keep getting array errors, etc. I'm not a PHP expert. I'm assuming I need to pull in the image to the /extension/module/category.php but I've no idea how. As per my image, images are coming thorough with no src. Without knowing what variable to bring through, I can't obviously know which to define for output.